# Reference Error when calling function inside setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I keep getting a Reference Error inside the setTimeout function.
Below is the code in javascript file

```
( function( $, undefined ) {

  $( document ).ready( init );

  function init() {
    registerEventListeners();
  }

  function registerEventListeners() {
    $( '.start_countdown').click( handleStart );
    $( '.end_countdown').click( handleEnd );
  }

  var countdown;
  var countdown_number;

  function handleStart() {
    countdown_number = 11;
    countdown_trigger(countdown_number);
  }

  function countdown_trigger() {
    if (countdown_number > 0) {
      countdown_number --;
      document.getElementById('countdown_text').innerHTML = countdown_number;
      if (countdown_number > 0) {
          countdown = setTimeout('countdown_trigger()', 1000);
      }
    }
  }

  function handleEnd() {
    clearTimeout(countdown);
  }

})( jQuery );
```

In the jade.js file:

```
extends layout

append scripts
  script(src='/javascripts/countDownRedirect.js')

block content
  h1= title

  p Redirecting you to your documents shortly

  div
    button.start_countdown#start Start Countdown
    button.end_countdown#end End Countdown

  div#countdown_text Placeholding text
```

Reference Error: 'countdown_trigger()' not defined

When the page is loaded everything appears to work fine.
Clicking the start button displays 10 but then throws the reference error.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use quotes in `setTimeout` you're invoking `eval` which is not a good idea. Try passing a reference to the function instead of a string:

```
countdown = setTimeout(countdown_trigger, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

To explain what's going on and why it doesn't work - when you pass a string to `setTimeout()`, the string is evaluated by `eval()` in the global scope.  That means that no local functions or variables are available in that global scope.  Since your `countdown_trigger()` function is declared inside another function, it is not in the global scope and thus won't be available to `eval()` and thus it doesn't work when you pass it to `setTimeout()`.

This is one of many reasons to never pass strings to `setTimeout()`.

Instead pass a real function reference which is evaluated in your current scope like this:

```
setTimeout(countdown_trigger, 1000);
```